# Jquery append input for 2 different input-sections

Tags: jquery, forms, append

Hi i use the following simple jquery script to append input. 
Source http://muiomuio.com/web-design/add-remove-items-with-jquery

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Add and Remove - jQuery tutorial</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var i = $('input').size() + 1;

    $('a.add').click(function() {
    $('<p><input type="text" value="input ' + i + '" name="input_field'+ i +'" /></p>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('#inputs');
        i++;
    });

    $('a.remove').click(function() {
            if(i > 2) {
        $('input:last').animate({opacity:"hide"}, "slow").remove();
    i--;
    }
    });

    $('a.reset').click(function() {
    while(i > 2) {
        $('input:last').remove();
        i--;
    }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add / remove text fields from webform</h1>

<a href="#" class="add"><img src="add.png" width="24" height="24" alt="add" title="add input" /></a> 
<a href="#" class="remove"><img src="remove.png" width="24" height="24" alt="remove input" /></a>
<a href="#" class="reset"><img src="reset.png" width="24" height="24" alt="reset" /></a>

<div id="inputs">
<p>
<input type="text" value="input 1" name="input_field1">
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know want to add more input fields

so i add this html

```
<div id="outputs">
<p>
<input type="text" value="output 1" name="output_field1">
</p>
```

how can i achieve that the

```
var i = $('input').size() + 1;
```

will be individually for every input section?

**EDITED:
the full script is the following. copy and paste will get you a full clone of mine.
Problem still exists**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Add and Remove - jQuery tutorial</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    var i = $('input').size() + 1;

    $('a.add').click(function() {

        $('<p><input type="text" value="input ' + i + '" name="input_field'+ i +'" /></p>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('#inputs');
        i++;
    });

    $('a.remove').click(function() {

    if(i > 2) {
        $('input:last').animate({opacity:"hide"}, "slow").remove();
        i--;

    }

    });

    $('a.reset').click(function() {

    while(i > 2) {
        $('input:last').remove();
        i--;
    }

    });




        $('a.add_o').click(function() {

        $('<p><input type="text" value="output ' + i + '" name="input_field'+ i +'" /></p>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('#outputs');
        i++;
    });

    $('a.remove_o').click(function() {

    if(i > 2) {
        $('input:last').animate({opacity:"hide"}, "slow").remove();
        i--;

    }

    });

    $('a.reset_o').click(function() {

    while(i > 2) {
        $('input:last').remove();
        i--;
    }

    });





});

</script>
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

h1 { font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.hide {visibility:hidden;}

img {border:none;}

input { 
    width:500px; 
    height:20px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#f7f7f7;
    border:1px solid #f0f0f0; 
    color:#333; 
    font-size:20px; 
    text-align:center; 
    line-height:120px;
    margin:0;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}

#inputs {
    width:520px;
    padding:0px 20px;
    border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Add / remove text fields from webform</h1>

<a href="#" class="add"><img src="http://muiomuio.com/tutorials/jquery/add-remove/add.png" width="24" height="24" alt="add" title="add input" /></a> 
<a href="#" class="remove"><img src="http://muiomuio.com/tutorials/jquery/add-remove/remove.png" width="24" height="24" alt="remove input" /></a>
<a href="#" class="reset"><img src="http://muiomuio.com/tutorials/jquery/add-remove/reset.png" width="24" height="24" alt="reset" /></a>

<div id="inputs">
<p>
<input type="text" value="input 1" name="input_field1">
</p>
</div>


<a href="#" class="add_o"><img src="http://muiomuio.com/tutorials/jquery/add-remove/add.png" width="24" height="24" alt="add" title="add input" /></a> 
<a href="#" class="remove_o"><img src="http://muiomuio.com/tutorials/jquery/add-remove/remove.png" width="24" height="24" alt="remove input" /></a>
<a href="#" class="reset_o"><img src="http://muiomuio.com/tutorials/jquery/add-remove/reset.png" width="24" height="24" alt="reset" /></a>

<div id="outputs">
<p>
<input type="text" value="output 1" name="output_field1">
</p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "will be individually for every input section"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I did what you want. The only thing you had to do, was make your code more consistent. Instead of asking `size()` once, you can just ask it every time you need it. This will be your `i`. I think this will be your full javascript. As you can see, I explicitly added the `'#inputs input'` question, so you count the right things. I think the `.size()` method is a bit deceiving, because it actually is a count method. Counting the numbers of objects that are matched.

```
$(function() 
{
    $('a.add').click(function() 
    {
        var i = $('#inputs input').size() + 1;
        var newItem = newTextField('input',i);
        appendItem(newItem, '#inputs');
    });

    $('a.remove').click(function() 
    {
        var i = $('#inputs input').size();

        // can't remove the last
        if(i > 1)
            removeItem('#inputs input:last'); // be sure that the input is inside your #inputs
    });

    $('a.reset').click(function() 
    {
        while($('#inputs input').size() > 1) 
        {
            $('#inputs input:last').remove();
        }
    });

    $('a.add_o').click(function() 
    {
        var i = $('#outputs input').size() + 1;
        var newItem = newTextField('output',i);
        appendItem(newItem, '#outputs');
    });

    $('a.remove_o').click(function() 
    {
        var i = $('#outputs input').size();

        // can't remove the last
        if(i > 1) 
            removeItem('#outputs input:last'); // be sure that the output is inside your #outputs

    });

    $('a.reset_o').click(function() 
    {
        while($('#outputs input').size() > 1) 
        {
            $('#outputs input:last').remove();
        }
    });

    /*
     * @param type: a string of input of output
     * @param i: the number to add to
     */
    function newTextField(type, i)
    {
        return '<p><input type="text" value="' + type + ' ' + i + '" name="input_field"' + i + '" /></p>';
    }

    /*
     * append the item animated to the $(selector)
     * @param item: the item:string to append
     * @param selector: the selector:string to append to
     */
    function appendItem(item, selector)
    {
        $(item).animate({ opacity: 'show' }, 'slow').appendTo(selector);
    }

    /*
     * remove an item animated
     * @param item: the item:string to remove
     */
    function removeItem(item)
    {
        $(item).animate({opacity:"hide"}, "slow").remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following:

```
$('input').each(function () {
$(this).size() + 1;

// ... rest of the code

});
```

Comment: Now I see what you mean. You can not just add a property to some selector (which is what you are trying). There are different ways to solve this. I will try to get an answer for you, which adds extra attributes to the html.

Answer (score 0):

Define your variable i globally.

i.e.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var i = 0;
    $(function() {
        i = $('input').size() + 1;
        $('a.add').click(function() {
            $('<p><input type="text" value="input ' + i + '" name="input_field' + i + '" /></p>').animate({
                opacity: "show"
            }, "slow").appendTo('#inputs');
            i++;
        });
        $('a.remove').click(function() {
            if (i > 2) {
                $('input:last').animate({
                    opacity: "hide"
                }, "slow").remove();
                i--;
            }
        });
        $('a.reset').click(function() {
            while (i > 2) {
                $('input:last').remove();
                i--;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(function() {
    var i = $('input').size() + 1;

    $('a.add').click(function() {
    $('<p><input type="text" value="input ' + i + '" name="input_field'+ i +'" /></p>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('#inputs');//first field added
    $('<p><input type="text" value="output ' + i + '" name="output_field'+ i +'" /></p>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('#inputs');// Second field added
        i=i+2;//increment by two fields;
    });

    $('a.remove').click(function() {
            if(i > 2) {
        $('input:last').animate({opacity:"hide"}, "slow").remove();//second field removed
        $('input:last').animate({opacity:"hide"}, "slow").remove();//first field removed
    i=i-2;//decrement by 2 fields
    }
    });

    $('a.reset').click(function() {
    while(i > 2) {
        $('input:last').remove();
        i--;
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: right. because you added 2 fields. if you don't increase by 2, then when you click "reset" it won't get rid of all the fields, only half of the added fields... if you want the counter to increment by 1 then you need to change the counters back to i++ and i-- and place TWO $('input:last').remove(); in the reset function...